# Confluence Project transfer from one company to another company

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api, confluence-macros

My company **ABC** is taken over by Company **PQR** and **ABC** has Confluence Project '*Proj1*' With lots of information contents in it. I want to move/copy/transfer/export project '*Proj1*' to new company **PQR** 's Confluence site with same project name  '*Proj1*' with all contents in it

Is this possible in Confluence Project?

Comment: Please help me here

Comment: When you say "Project" do you mean "Space"?